# How to overcome same-origin-policy from iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

I'm basically trying to display a second website, belonging to the same organization but hosted on a different domain name, in an Iframe.  And I'm trying to pass in some data from the iframe to the parent frame.

Parent frame = foo.com,

Iframe = bar.com

If I try to pass in the data from the iframe via `parent.setData( data )`, that gives me a same-origin policy error.

So I made a wrapper around this code, hosted at `foo.com/js/wrapper.js`, which contains this function:

```
var Foo = {};
Foo.setData = function(data)
{
    parent.setData(data);
}
```

So now my Iframe on `bar.com` is doing:

```
<script src="http://foo.com/js/wrapper.js"></script>
<script>
   Foo.setData( someData );
</script>
```

However, even that is giving me a security error on the `parent.setData` line, even through `wrapper.js` is hosted on the parent domain.

Is there any other way to overcome this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: @Quentin Any chance of any example code?

Comment: There's an entire subsection on that page titled "Example"!

Comment: @Quentin Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://foo.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://bar.com').

Comment: Sounds like you gave `postMessage`'s second argument the wrong value.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, you were right, I was doing `window.postMessage` rather than `parent.postMessage`. It works now. Feel free to post an answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `postMessage`, read up on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Edit: sorry, didn't see all of the comments saying the same thing

Comment: Your server could force no `www` or you could parse the parent window from `window.top.location` and use that as the targetOrigin (ensuring of course that it was one of your whitelisted domains)

Answer (score 2):

Another fun way to get around this policy is to hijack the child window.location.hash, as it is also visible to both scripting engines.